# Index min value for all element in a list

Tags: c#, collections

Let me try again..
I have two classes:

```
class OrdenO
{
    public int id_orden_O { get; set; }
    public int Ei_O { get; set; }
    public int Ii_O { get; set; }
    public int Si_O { get; set; }
    public int DTi_O { get; set; }
    public int Ui_O { get; set; }
    public int K_O { get; set; }
    public int Q_O { get; set; }
    public List<int> TT;
}
```

And Class Muelle

```
class Muelle
{
    public int id_muelle { get; set; }
    public int Lk { get; set; }
    public int Sk { get; set; }
}
```

And here, I have all elements in both Lists Collection:

```
List<OrdenO> myClassArray = new List<OrdenO>()
{
    new OrdenO{id_orden_O=1, Ei_O= 60, Ii_O= 180, Si_O=0, DTi_O=0, Ui_O=0, K_O=0, Q_O=0, TT= new List<int>{ 36, 36}},
    new OrdenO{id_orden_O=2, Ei_O= 0, Ii_O= 120, Si_O=0, DTi_O=0, Ui_O=0, K_O=0, Q_O=0, TT= new List<int>{ 18, 8}},
};
List<Muelle> mydock = new List<Muelle>()
{
    new Muelle{id_muelle=1, Lk=0, Sk=0},
    new Muelle{id_muelle=2, Lk=0, Sk=0}
};
```

Inside of my list `myclassarray` I have another list `TT`, and I would like to know how can I get the index min value of `TT` for each element of `myclassarray`.

Comment: This is not C# coding convention, you should change for better reading

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking for. What 'index min value'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assmuming I understand you correctly - you want to pull the lowest value of each `TT` list from each item in `myClassArray`, this should do it:

```
foreach (var item in myClassArray)
{
    var min = item.TT.Min();
    // use min
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var i in myClassArray)
{
  int index = i.TT.IndexOf(i.TT.Min());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
IEnumerable<int> allminTTIndices = myClassArray
        .Select(o => o.TT.Select((tt, i) => new {TT=tt,Index=i})
                         .OrderBy(x => x.TT)
                         .First().Index);
```

Which returns all indices of the lowest `TT` value for each item in `myClassArray`.

However, the purpose of `List<Muelle> mydock = new List<Muelle>()` remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the min value of TT

var lowest = myClassArray.SelectMany(o => o.TT).OrderBy(i => i).FirstOrDefault();
OR

var lowest = myClassArray.SelectMany(o => o.TT).Min();